# Are all binary-additive stream ciphers reciprocal?

Tags: stream-cipher, information-theory

I'm writing a thesis focused on [Maurer's provably-secure stream cipher](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00191321#page-1). Long story short, this cipher works by expanding a short key into a long keystream and then XORring this keystream with the plaintext in order to obtain the ciphertext (and vicecersa).

Take this definition of a **binary-additive stream cipher**: a cipher where the plaintext, ciphertext and keystream are binary strings and where the ciphertext is produced as a XOR addition of the plaintext and the keystream.

Also, take this definition of a **reciprocal cipher**: a cipher in which the encryption and decryption algorithms are identical (they're the same *involution*).

With these two definitions, can I state that binary-additive stream ciphers are all reciprocal ciphers? I think so, since if the ciphertext is the XOR of plaintext and keystream, than the plaintext must be the XOR of the keystream and the ciphertext.

Comment: The inverse of XOR is XOR, so yes.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: Note that this isn't the case for CFB mode, which is a xor based stream cipher but doesn't fulfill your particular definition.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I don't know what CFB mode is :(. If I understand correcly from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_feedback_.28CFB.29), it's something that turns a cipher into a *self-synchronizing* (or *asynchronous*) stream cipher; binary-additive stream cipher are, by definition, *synchronous* stream cipher so I don't think that that would be a problem. Again, I'm not sure I'm getting this right :).

Comment: @whatyouhide: Welcome to crypto.SE! $\;$ Looks like you are doing fine; I do not spot that you wrote anything silly in question or comment.

Answer (score 1):

Since additive stream ciphers are involutions, i.e.,
$$
E_K(\cdot)=D_K(\cdot)
$$
for all possible keys $K$,
they are also reciprocal.